# Problema con mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente duda, estoy haciendo un buscador, que me busque en mi base de datos un producto que contenga alguna letra en su nombre, hago la consulta en phpmyadmin y todo bien, me funciona, el problema viene cuando le paso por parametro desde el input, y no se como hacer para que el parametro pase por el bindParam, aca les dejo el codigo, me podrian dar una mano? no hace mucho que empece con esto de php, muchas gracias!

```
$Buscar= $_POST{'busca'};

$sql ="select p.idProducto, p.nombre_producto, p.precio, c.nombre_categoria 
       as categoria, p.stock, p.detalles from productos p join categorias
       c on c.id_categoria = p.id_categoria where p.idEstadoEliminacion = 1
                      and nombre_producto like '%:busca%'";
//
                    $sentencia = $con->prepare($sql);
                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':busca', $Buscar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar reemplazando la última parte de tu consulta con:

```
and p.nombre_producto like CONCAT('%', :busca, '%')";
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!!!! fue excelente tu respuesta!!! Genio!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta forma

```
and nombre_producto like %:busca% ";

$sentencia-> bindParam(':busca', $Buscar);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! pero la probé y no funcionó, la de concatenar de RockoDev si me trajo resultados. Igualmete MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS POR RESPONDERME!!!

Comment: ok, entonces marca la de el como resuelta bro... exitos